# C#: Get Bytearray from IConvertible

Tags: c#, arrays, iconvertible

I'm currently working on a small project where I edit a binary file. Therefor I want to use the IConvertible Interface, since I can't create a Getter and Setter for every type.
Currently I'm working on the Setter which needs to convert the IConvertible object into a bytearray.

The Setter currently looks like this:
`public void SetValue(UInt32 Offset, IConvertible Value) { }`

Does anybody know a way in order to get a bytearray from the IConvertible Object, since BitConverter doesn't offer a native way of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IConvertible` is not intended for this scenario, as reflected by the primary methods of `IConvertible` (`ToString`, `ToUInt64`, etc). There *is* an auxiliary `ToType` which *could* work, but most types **do not support** `ToType` with `byte[]` (for `conversionType`). If it did, then this would work:

```
var blob = Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(byte[]));
```

However, this is **not** something you should do, and it is not the intended usage. Frankly, your serialization details should usually exist **separate to** the objects.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your response. I'll edit my code to use a different method. Thank you for pointing this out to me. :)